# TV Episode (anthology?), sleeper ship with arguing old men

Tags: story-identification, tv

looking for short film about two old men arguing onboard a sleeper ship.

I think it was an episode of a TV scifi anthology series, I'm struggling to remember when but guessing about ten years ago, maybe less. I've looked at all the recent ones I can think of (Electric Dreams, Dimension 404, Metal Hurlant Chronicles even Black Mirror) but couldn't see anything familiar.

All I can remember is that it's a ship travelling to a far destination for some reason over a great length of time (start a colony or something I guess), there's one guy looking after things with another turning up later, maybe out of hypersleep (why I think it's a sleeper ship not a generational one). I can't recall why, maybe there's a problem and they're arguing over the best course of action, maybe self-destruction is mooted. They finally reach their destination only to find newer, faster ships have beaten them to it (that old chesnut :) )

Only other detail is I think it was two quite distinguished older male actors, maybe at the time quite surprising to see them in a tv show, just the two of them until the very end.

I can't recall anything about what the ship looked like.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Pandorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandorum)

Comment: Definitely not Pandorum, was a short one-off story for sure. Pandorum is great though :) Thanks.